# Naming Variables using Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Even though my problem is pretty simple, since I'm new to spark having issues resolving it.

The normal python query for my issue is the following:

```
for line in file('schedule.txt'):
  origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=line.split(',')
```

I could read the file as

```
sched=sc.textFile('/PATH/schedule.txt')
```

But when I was trying the following code:

```
  origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=sched.split(',')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ba0e8c07ca89> in <module>()
----> 1 origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=sched.split(',')

AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I could split the file using lambda function. But don't know how to create those 5 variable names.

If somebody can please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sched=sc.textFile('/PATH/schedule.txt')` returns an `RDD` which is a different datatype than a python file object and supports a different [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD). The equivalent of your python code would be something like:

```
sched=sc.textFile('/PATH/schedule.txt')
# extract values
vals = sched.map(lambda line:line.split(','))
# now you can do some processing, for example sum price
price = vals.reduce(lambda v1,v2:v1[4]+v2[4])
# or just collect the raw values
raw_vals = vals.collect()
```

**update:**
if you want to be able to access the values of each line as local variables you could define a dedicated function instead of just a lambda and pass that to `.map()`:

```
def process_line(line):
    origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=line.split(',')
    # do whatever
    # remember to return a result

sche.map(process_line)
```

**update2:**

The specific processing you want to do on the file is not trivial because it requires writing to a shared variable (`flights`). Instead, i'd suggest grouping the lines by `orig,dest`, then collecting the results and inserting into a dict:

```
flights_data = sched.map(lambda line: ((line[0],line[1]),tuple(line[2:]))).groupByKey().collect()
flights = {f:ds for f,ds in flights_data}
```

Comment: Thanks yurip for your answer. But my issue is not split the dataset. My issue is split the dataset in 5 variables and assigning the data into 5 seperate variables. The next few codes are the following: flights={} flights.setdefault((origin,dest),[]) flights[(origin,dest)].append((depart,arrive,int(price))). For this I need separate variables to call. So the question is how to do the seperations.

Comment: Thanks a ton yurib for your help! Both your codes ran perfectly fine. But I still have to figure out how I can use the local variables in my processing (apart from the one you have shown.) Thanks again!

Comment: @Beta you can read about sparks options for shared variables. However, I don't think they apply for your case. In order to preserve distributability, sparks shared variables capabilities are very limited. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables

Comment: Thanks Yurib! I'll look into it.